# How to create a pseudo-random sequence with a 16 bit LFSR

Tags: vhdl, xilinx-ise

I am trying to generate a random sequence of 16 bit.
The problem is that the output is getting undefined state. I feel that this is due to parallel processing  in those xor statements. So I have put in delays but it still doesn't work.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity random_data_generator is
  port (
    por             :   in  STD_LOGIC;
    sys_clk         :   in  STD_LOGIC;
    random_flag     :   in  STD_LOGIC;
    random_data     :   out STD_LOGIC_vector (15 downto 0)
  );
end random_data_generator;

architecture Behavioral of random_data_generator is
  signal q          :   std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  signal n1,n2,n3   :   std_logic;


begin
  process(sys_clk)
  begin
  if(por='0') then 
    q<= "1001101001101010";
    elsif(falling_edge(sys_clk)) then
        if(random_flag='1') then
        n1<= q(15) xor q(13);
        n2<= n1 xor q(11) after 10 ns;
        n3<= n2 xor q(10) after 10 ns;
        q<= q(14 downto 0) & n3 after 10 ns;
    end if;
    end if;
  end process;
  random_data <= q;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Remember:  "Anyone who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin." - _John von Neumann 1951_. A PRNG will never generate truly random numbers.

Comment: Xilinx application note [XAPP052](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp052.pdf) shows how to implement a PRNG with minimal hardware resources. The PoC IP core [PoC.arith.prng](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/arith/arith_prng.vhdl?ts=2) is a configurable PRNG for 3 to 168 bits output values that implements PRNG polynomials provided by XAPP052.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making some small structural changes to your LFSR:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity random_data_generator is
    port (
        por:                in  std_logic;
        sys_clk:            in  std_logic;
        random_flag:        in  std_logic;
        random_data:        out std_logic_vector (15 downto 0)
    );
end entity random_data_generator;

architecture behavioral of random_data_generator is
    signal q:             std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal n1, n2, n3:    std_logic;
begin
    process (por, sys_clk) -- ADDED por to sensitivity list
    begin
        if por = '0' then 
            q <= "1001101001101010";
        elsif falling_edge(sys_clk) then
            if random_flag = '1' then
                -- REMOVED intermediary products as flip flops
                q <= q(14 downto 0) & n3;  -- REMOVED after 10 ns;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    -- MOVED intermediary products to concurrent signal assignments:
    n1 <= q(15) xor q(13);
    n2 <= n1 xor q(11); --  REMOVED after 10 ns;
    n3 <= n2 xor q(10); --  REMOVED after 10 ns;

    random_data <= q;
end architecture behavioral;
```

These changes remove the n1, n2, and n3 flip flops by promoting those assignments to concurrent signal assignment statements. The fundamental issue generating 'U's is that these flip flops were not initialized. They were flip flops because their assignment was inside the if statement with an elsif condition on the falling edge of sys_clk.

Adding a testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity rng_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of rng_tb is
    signal por:         std_logic;
    signal sys_clk:     std_logic := '0';
    signal random_flag: std_logic;
    signal random_data: std_logic_vector (15 downto 0);
begin
DUT:
    entity work.random_data_generator
        port map (
            por => por,
            sys_clk => sys_clk,
            random_flag => random_flag,
            random_data => random_data
        );
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 5 ns;
        sys_clk <= not sys_clk;
        if now > 2800 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;
STIMULI:
    process
    begin
        por <= '1';
        random_flag <= '0';
        wait until falling_edge(sys_clk);
        por <= '0';
        wait until falling_edge(sys_clk);
        wait for 1 ns;
        por <= '1';
        wait until falling_edge(sys_clk);
        random_flag <= '1';
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Analyzing both, elaborating and simulating the testbench gives:

[image: rng_tb.png]

Showing a pseudo-random sequence with a length longer than 16 using a 16 bit Linear Feedback Shift Register (LFSR).